# How to ignore some projects in the solution for Github

Tags: github

I have a solution and there are seven projects in it. I want some projects to exclude from sharing on Github. I just want to share one or two projects. But it sends all of the projects to my github page. I'm new on github. Hope i could explain my problem.

Answer (score 0):

there is a solution, you create a repository for each subproject with the possibility to put them private or public.